# Deduce GARCH(1,1) to the stochastic variance model

Tags: garch

Here is the proof that the limit of GARCH(1,1)
$$\sigma_n^2 = \gamma V_L + \alpha u_{n-1}^2 + \beta\sigma_{n-1}^2$$
is equivalent to stochastic process of variance
$$d V = \alpha(V_L - V) dt + \xi VdW.$$
We have already assumed return $u_{n-1}$ is $(0,\sigma_{n-1}^2)$-normal, then $u^2_{n-1}$ can't be normal. But author said that
$$u^2_{n-1} = \sigma_{n-1}^2 + \sqrt{2}\sigma_{n-1}^2\varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a random sample from a standard normal?[image]

Comment: From which book is your excerpt taken?

Comment: @Gordon this is the solution  of John Hull's book  `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives  Solutions Manual Eighth Edition`  `page 171 Problem 22.14`

Comment: @Gordon I know that for a $\chi^2$-process $V,$ the limit of $V-E[V]$ trends to a Brownian motion on the distribution, but I don't how to take the limit here?